# How do you introduce a song or a sung part right after a dialogue?

Tags: creative-writing, formatting

So I was thinking this would look really odd. Do you have to use the same format as you introduce a spoken part, or can you do this? And what might be the alternatives to this? I am asking, because this looks really odd.

> "This is wild!" she said. "Really wild!"
>
> She then decided to sing:
>
> *Cruella de Vil, Cruella de Vil!
>
> If she doesn't share you, no evil thing will
>
> To see her is to take a sudden chill
>
> Cruella, Cruella!
>
> She's like a spider waiting for the kill
>
> Look out for Cruella de Vil.*

Comment: Be careful: this may be expensive.